# How to load text from UITextField and show it in UITableView every time textfield return text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray

**I am aware this question has been asked before but the answer is not clear**

> The problem is that the`UITableview` is using data from`viewDidLoad` method 
>   where the`NSMuatableArray` has been allocated and initialised but contains void. But in the textfield method of`textFieldDidEndEditing`,`NSMutableArray` do contain text from textField.

I have a single viewController and texField and tableview exist in it having dataSource set to the same viewController.
**The problem is how can I pass that value to`UITableView`**

> viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextField;
@property NSString *content;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *textFieldArray;

@end
```

> viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textField{
    self.content = [textField text];
    NSLog(@"content is %@", self.content);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


-(bool)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *) textField {

    [self.textFieldArray addObject:self.content];
    [textField setText:@""];
    NSLog(@"Array inside field did end editing is %@", self.textFieldArray);
    return YES;
}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.textFieldArray.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.textFieldArray[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textFieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"add more task", nil];




    NSLog(@"box in viewDidLoad ris %@", self.textFieldArray);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: add the text into array and reload the uitableview

Comment: You have to reload tableview in textFieldDidEndEditing method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vivek's Answer is perfectly fine, except that fact you don;t need to reload table unless it's really necessary (extra processing time and all you know), so instead of reloading entire table you can add just one row, like this:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [_tableDSArray addObject:textField.text];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tableDSArray.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}
```

Comment: This is really good solution, thanks for letting me know about this.

Answer (score 2):

In your `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method after fetching the text from textfield reload the table view so that the new value get reflected. Do it this way:

```
[self.textFieldArray addObject:self.content];
[textField setText:@""];

// Your code is missing the following line
[tableView reloadData]; // tableView is instance of your table view

NSLog(@"Array inside field did end editing is %@", self.textFieldArray);
return YES;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I don't know how I miss this.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(bool)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *) textField {

    [self.textFieldArray addObject:self.content];
    [textField setText:@""];
    [tableView reloadData]; //Reload tableview
    return YES;
}
```

Call tableview reload in textFieldDidEndEditing delegate

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(bool)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *) textField {
    [self.textFieldArray addObject:self.content];
    [textField setText:@""];
    [tableView setdelegate:nil];
    [tableView setdatasource:nil];
    [tableView setdelegate:self];
    [tableView setdatasource:self];
    [tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Updated With Entered Text:\n%@",self.textFieldArray); 
    return YES;
    }
```